# How to pivot and groupby PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I pivot and group by country this dataframe and use YEAR as column

```
pandas.DataFrame = (data  = {'COUNTRY': ['USA', 'USA', 'UK', 'UK'],
 'YEAR': [1999, 2000, 1999, 2000],
 'VALUE': [99, 111, 88, 100]} )
```

[image]

Such as I get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
print(df.pivot(index="COUNTRY", columns="YEAR", values="VALUE").reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
YEAR COUNTRY  1999  2000
0         UK    88   100
1        USA    99   111
```